# Jenkins Job-DSL: How to accept URL over Https with own root-ca signed certificate?

Tags: ssl, groovy, jenkins, keystore, jenkins-job-dsl

I want to read a xml stream over HTTPS. The webserver has a certificate that was signed by our own-created inoffical CA.

I know I need to import the CA cert to make my Groovy Job DSL Script work.

**Where do I need to import the ca cert or how can I define my own trustStore to make it work?**

What I tried before:

- Importing CA cert with keytool to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_40\lib\security\cacert
- Importing CA cert with keytool to C:\Program Files (x86)\jenkins\jre\lib\security\cacert

When I try the connection with groovyConsole after importing the CA cert to cacert trustStore everything work, but in Jenkins not.

So I tried to set a trustStore in my Job DSL script without success. Still recieving the cert chain error exception:

```
def addr          = "https://example.com:8443/svn/"
def authString    = "user:pass".getBytes().encodeBase64().toString()
def jobNamePrefix = "Job"

println("${WORKSPACE}\\epedev.keystore")
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "${WORKSPACE}\\epedev.keystore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");

def conn = addr.toURL().openConnection()
```

Console-Snippet:

```
Processing provided DSL script
C:\Jenkins\ps\seed\Seed PS Projects from SVN\workspace\epedev.keystore
FATAL: Unable to run script
java.io.IOException: Unable to run script
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslScriptLoader.runDslEngineForParent(DslScriptLoader.java:92)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslScriptLoader.runDslEngine(DslScriptLoader.java:123)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.ExecuteDslScripts.perform(ExecuteDslScripts.java:216)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:408)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl$GetBeanMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3500)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:61)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
    at script.run(script:12)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslScriptLoader.runDslEngineForParent(DslScriptLoader.java:80)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 41 more
Started calculate disk usage of build
Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
Started calculate disk usage of workspace
Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
Finished: FAILURE
```

UPDATE:

I also started groovyConsole with Jenkins JRE. It's also working. So the cacerts keystore contains the working ca cert. But why does it not work in Jenkins script console or Job DSL Plugin. What's wrong here?

Comment: have you tried to run the groovy script from within the `groovyConsole`?

Comment: btw: I guess it depends on how your jenkins is installed which java environment and thus which keystore is used. Have you already checked which jre/jdk is used or have you searched for all keystores on your machine?

Comment: I mentioned that I tried my script successfully in groovyConsole. I logged java.home so I know, that the JobDSL script uses C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jre. But I already imported the certificate to this cacerts keystore.

Comment: so, that's indeed very strange... Have you tried to get some more detailed debug infos through setting `-Djavax.net.debug=all`? This Blog entry might also be helpful: https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https

Comment: In older releases (1.35 and older) the Job DSL plugin did some classspath magic to bring it's own Groovy runtime. Make sure to try the latest release. And also test your script the Jenkins Script Console (e.g. http://localhost:8080/script). If your script is working there, it is most probably a problem with the Job DSL plugin.

Comment: It's the lastest Jenkins and Plugin version.

Comment: I tried on script console. Same result, no success. I don't know how to set `-Djavax.net.debug=all` for Jenkins. Do I need to start Jenkins with this parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working after I restarted the Jenkins windows service. Before that I always restartet Jenkins in the application itself. It seems like there is a difference between restarting the service and reboot Jenkins in the console.

After that the CA cert I imported to C:\Program Files (x86)\jenkins\jre\lib\security\cacert was found.